# Why my VPS IP is not pointing to server base directory in Lampp on Ubuntu

Tags: server, apache2, lamp, vps

I had buy a vps server with Ubuntu installed on it. I added the ip in the A record of my domain then domian is sucessfully pointing to my server. I installed Lampp on server and both the domain and ip are pointing to the base directory of Lampp as **/opt/lampp/htdocs**. All the things are fine till now.

But then I added the following code into **/opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf**, to point my domain to specific directory. It also work fine and my domain is now pointing to this **/opt/lampp/htdocs/webproject/public**.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@chamberstock.com
    ServerName chamberstock.com
    ServerAlias www.chamberstock.com
    DocumentRoot /opt/lampp/htdocs/webproject/public
</VirtualHost>
```

But the problem is that my Vps ip is also pointing to **/opt/lampp/htdocs/webproject/public**, however it needed to point here **/opt/lampp/htdocs/** which is the root directory

If you think I don't make proper configuration to point my domain to specific directory then tell me how to configure Lampp server for this.

Comment: Hello, please read and clarify your question, because it is unclear what you are asking. Regards!

Comment: In lampp the root directoru is /opt/lampp/htdocs. After installing lampp on my vpd my ip address was pointing to this root directory, ok. But when i make some changings as I described the ip address of my server is not pointing to root directory.